# Git | Pequeña duda con el comando git push y otros

Tags: git, github

Realmente es una duda un poco boba pero llevo tiempo preguntandomelo, cual es la diferencia entre `git push origin master` y `git push -u origin master` se que solo es una -u, pero me gustaria saber que significa y que hace.

En general quisiera saber por que a algunos comandos de git se les adicciona "caracteristicas" como por ejemplo; `-m` o en algunos casos son doble guion `--` siento como si me estuviera perdiendo algo importante de la sintaxis, es necesario que me aprenda aqueyas variaciones seguidas de los guiones?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `-u` en un `push` sirve para configurar la rama `upstream` de la rama en la que estás trabajando de tal forma que con solo hacer `git push` trabajando sobre dicha rama, no tengas que indicar de nuevo el remoto y la rama (remota) a la que quieres empujarla y también es la rama desde la que se van a bajar cambios si haces `git pull` (sin indicar más nada) al trabajar sobre la rama local en la que estás.

El `--` sirve para indicarle a git que ya terminaste de indicarle opciones y que lo que viene ahora son parámetros normales (normalmente, archivos). No aplica solo para git. `--` probablemente es un standard que aplica para muuuuchos comandos con el mismo efecto.

Y sobre `-m`, seguramente es una opción de un comando (en este caso, de git). Cada comando tiene muchas opciones, tendrías que leer el manual del comando en cuestión para saber cuales hay disponibles y para qué sirve cada una de dichas opciones.